# Try to make beaker session work with gunicorn in python Bottle framework

Tags: python, bottle, gunicorn, beaker

I am using bottle to write a small web program and name the following source file `index.py`. I also use beaker session library in the program. When I run the code using `python index.py` everything goes right. But when I use `gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf index:app` I get error message like this saying that beaker key `beaker.session` doesn't exist. How can I change the code to make things work again in gunicorn server?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bottle-0.12.7-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/bottle.py", line 857, in _handle
    self.trigger_hook('before_request')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bottle-0.12.7-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/bottle.py", line 640, in trigger_hook
    return [hook(*args, **kwargs) for hook in self._hooks[__name][:]]
  File "/Users/yizeng/Documents/python_projects/simple-courses/index.py", line 17, in setup_request
    request.session = request.environ['beaker.session']
KeyError: 'beaker.session'
```

source code for `index.py`:

```
import os, sys, bottle
from bottle import debug, route, request, run, Bottle, static_file, hook
from apps import model, views
from beaker.middleware import SessionMiddleware


app = bottle.app()

session_options = {
        'session.type': 'file',
        'session.cookie_expires': 300,
        'session.data_dir': './data',
        'session.auto': True
    }
@hook('before_request')
def setup_request():
    request.session = request.environ['beaker.session']

@app.route('/assets/<filepath:path>')
def server_static(filepath):
    return static_file(filepath, root='assets')

@app.route('/test')
def test():
    s = request.environ.get('beaker.session')
    s['test'] = s.get('test', 0) + 1
    s.save()
    return 'Test counter: %d' % s['test']

app_session = SessionMiddleware(app, session_options)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(app=app_session)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't need the last block `if __name...` at all. Gunicorn running the *index* module's *app* "varibale" as a WSIG means it should spin up an instance of your bottle app.